# Sprites not displaying

Tags: css, sprite, rollover

Sprite rollover images not displaying.

The goal is to have a row of icons with a rollover controlled by CSS.

Currently, the code below does not display any images...what am I missing?

**CSS:**

```
    #social {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    height: 15px;
}
#social li {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    display: inline; 
    height: 15px;
    float: left;
}
#social li.last{
    margin-right:0px;
}
#social li a {
    background-image: url("../images/icon_twitter.png") 0px 0px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 18px;
}
#social li#social-twitter a{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#social li#social-twitter a:hover {
    background-position: 0px -15px;
}
#social li#social-youtube a{
    background-position: -18 top;
}
#social li#social-youtube a:hover {
    background-position: -18 -15px;
}
#social span {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="social">
<li id="social-twitter"><a href="#"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
<li id="social-youtube" class="last"><a href="#"><span>Youtube</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `background-position: -18 top;` 18 is missing the `unit` ;-)

Comment: have you made sure the image is the correct image? its named `icon_twitter` also make sure its not 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the background position within `background-image`.

Change this:

```
background-image: url("../images/icon_twitter.png") 0px 0px;
```

To this:

```
background-image: url("../images/icon_twitter.png"); 
background-position: 0px 0px;
```

Comment: Or just: background: url("../images/icon_twitter.png") 0px 0px;

Comment: The background-position fixed it! Thank you.

Comment: @user2970432, Nice one! If you could mark this answer as 'accepted' if you're happy with it, that would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** You are using `background-position` with `background-image` property

**Solution:** Either use only `background` property or use `background-position` separately

```
background: color url(src) repeat position;
```

or

```
background-image: url(src);
background-position: position;
```

Your code should like this:

```
background: url("../images/icon_twitter.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
```

*Note: You should use `px` (or any other unit) with non zero numbers and zero should be used without unit.*